# strange white line in image after loading

Tags: html, image

[alt text http://www.shrani.si/f/2o/st/4iqzohKo/tmp.gif](http://www.shrani.si/f/2o/st/4iqzohKo/tmp.gif)

After loading image i get strange white line. After image is loading white line dissapear. I am loading image with html:

```
<img src="/images/p1.png" alt="" width="666" height="196" />
```

Comment: Can you show a live link? And you seem to be using the GIF format for a photograph, something that doesn't work too well anyway - you'd be better off with JPG.

Comment: we can't see your html code. Please edit your question, mark the html code and press the code button of the editor (the one with the ones and zeros on it)

Comment: Does it do it without the `width` and `height` arguments?  Sometimes resizing images in the browser produces strange artifacts.

Comment: I think it's because you're using the devil's number for the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the actual image size differs subtly from the dimensions you specify:

```
width="666" height="196"
```

try removing the width and height settings and see whether it works better then.

As I said in the commnent already, you seem to be using GIF to store a photographic motive. If it's not your intention to get that raster effect, JPEG is the better format for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean - but is this perhaps a jpeg or gif that shows contents while loading ([interlaced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlace_(bitmaps)))? If so, the only thing you can do to fix this would be to re-save the image as non-interlaced.